# Modal on wp menu link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to learn some new stuff but I stuck to something easy.
I managed to manipulate a link from wp menu using this code

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'menu_item_data_toggle', 10, 2 );

function menu_item_data_toggle( $atts, $item) {
  // Manipulate attributes
  if ( 74 == $item -> ID )
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'modal';

  return $atts;
}
```

but I need to use this modal with "if" attribute for login user and I can't figure how to.
The code for this modal I want to use is from a button

```
<?php
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    $account_manage = '<a href="'.esc_url( classifieds_get_permalink_by_tpl( 'page-tpl_my_profile' ) ).'" class="login-action">'.classifieds_get_option( 'my_profile_looks' ).'</a>';
    $submit_ad = add_query_arg( array( $classifieds_slugs['subpage'] => 'submit_ad' ), classifieds_get_permalink_by_tpl('page-tpl_my_profile') );
    $modal = '';
}
else{
    $account_manage = '<a href="#login" data-toggle="modal" class="login-action">'.classifieds_get_option( 'login_looks' ).'</a>';
    $submit_ad = '#register';
    $modal = 'data-toggle="modal"';
}
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
if ( isset( $locations[ 'top-navigation' ] ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'top-navigation',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav clearfix',
        'container'         => false,
        'echo'              => true,
        'items_wrap'        => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s',
        'depth'             => 10,
        'walker'            => new classifieds_walker,
    ) );
}
if(get_option('users_can_register')){
    echo '<li>'.$account_manage.'</li><li class="submit-add"><a href="'.esc_attr__( $submit_ad ).'" '.$modal.' class="btn">'.esc_html__( 'SUBMIT AD', 'classifieds' ).'</a></li></ul>';
}
?>
```

Can you please me give me a hint to figure it out and use that menu link with this modal attributes?
Thank you!